Верно ли поставлены знаки?
Вот что значит: «В тихом омуте черти водятся».
Объясните, пожалуйста, если есть ошибка.

• По поводу кавычек
У Розенталя (Слова автора внутри прямой речи, примечание):

2. Не выделяется кавычками прямая речь в следующих случаях:
1) если нет точного указания, кому она принадлежит, или если приводится общеизвестная пословица, поговорка:
Про Ивашку Бровкина говорили: крепкий (А. Т.); Дома и хворать легче и жить дешевле; и недаром говорится: дома и стены помогают (Ч.)...

• По поводу прописной буквы
У Лопатина (Знаки препинания при цитатах):

§ 143. Цитата, включенная в авторское предложение на правах его компонента, выделяется кавычками (но начинается со строчной буквы), знаки препинания употребляются только те, которые диктуются самим авторским предложением...

• Рассуждения
Начинаем поговорку, являющуюся частью предложения (значит = означает), с маленькой буквы, двоеточие не ставим, кавычки не ставим (если только выражение не является дословным повтором чьей-то реплики).
• Примеры
Единственная дочь, отличница. Занималась музыкой и танцами. В скандалах никаких не замечена. Да просто идеальная девочка. Но я-то понимаю, что только на показуху. Вот что значит в тихом омуте черти водятся (Л. Игнатова. Ты моё безумие).
— Вот это поворот, — тихо присвистнул Стас. — А по ней и не скажешь... Вот что значит в тихом омуте черти водятся! Или вы шутите? (М. Серова. Спасти нельзя сдаться).

Контекст нужен, а то смысл неясен.
Обычно пословицы не цитируются по правилам прямой речи, а просто встраиваются в текст на правах членов предложений. В этом случае нет там слов автора и дословных высказываний. Пример из Карты слов: Вот что значит в тихом омуте черти водятся.
Лана Александровна Игнатова, Ты моё безумие, 2021

Вообще говоря, если пословица применяется в тексте, то запись делается без кавычек и со строчной буквы, а выражение встраивается в предложение. Примеры можно посмотреть в КАРТЕ СЛОВ.

Например, такой фрагмент: Что это значит? А вот что значит: в тихом омуте черти водятся. Или: Недаром исстари люди толкуют, что в тихом омуте черти водятся, а в лесном болоте плодятся…

Кавычки ставятся  в тех случаях, если в тексте есть слова "выражение, пословица". Тогда двоеточие не нужно, но буква прописная.

Что означает выражение «В тихом омуте черти водятся»?  Выражение "В тихом омуте черти водятся" означает, что непримечательный человек может проявить себя неожиданным образом.
Также у Розенталя:
Он вспомнил пословицу «За двумя зайцами погонишься — ни одного не поймаешь» и отказался от первоначального плана

Вообще говоря, можно выделить ТРИ ВАРИАНТА оформления речи с пословицами:

Самый частотный вариант — это непосредственное использование в речи.

В этом случае нет никаких знаков — ни кавычек, ни двоеточия, ни прописной буквы.
Все примеры приведены в Карте слов, включая вариант, наиболее близкий к заданному в вопросе: Вот что значит в тихом омуте черти водятся.

Второй вариант — это вариант с приложением (пословица, выражение и т. д.)

Здесь другая грамматика: двоеточия нет, но  сам текст пословицы  пишется с прописной буквы и заключен  в кавычки (он цитируется).
Образец из Розенталя:
Он вспомнил пословицу «За двумя зайцами погонишься — ни одного не поймаешь» и отказался от первоначального плана.

Третий вариант — цитирование по образу классической прямой речи.

В этом случае полный набор опознавательных знаков — двоеточие, кавычки, прописная буква.
Например: В известной русской пословице говорится: "В тихом омуте черти водятся".
Для ЗАДАННОГО ВОПРОСА также возможен этот вариант оформления: Вот что значит (пословица, выражение): «В тихом омуте черти водятся?»
Поэтому для решения нужен был контекст.
ЗАКЛЮЧЕНИЕ (что я могу еще сказать)

Тема оформления дословных высказываний довольно сложна для пользователей русского языка. Это связано со многими причинами: как с разнообразием синтаксических конструкций и недостаточным количеством нормированных примеров в правилах, так и с отсутствием его системного изложения по грамматическим показателям.

Прописные буквы, двоеточие, кавычки — когда их писать, а когда не надо? Почему именно так надо писать?  Это те вечные вопросы, которые приходится решать. Вот и ищутся наугад подходящие правила (из Розенталя или ПАС) и примеры из литературных источников. Может, какой и подойдет.

Но все же лучше разобраться с грамматикой и понять, как строится тот или другой из возможных вариантов. Самый лучший способ — дать каждому варианту название. Вот уж точно: "как вы яхту назовете, так она и поплывет".

И еще замечание по ИНФОРМАТИВНОСТИ стиля ответов.
Желательно сначала привести правильный вариант 
ответа с кратким обоснованием, а потом уже 
рассуждения, правила, примеры. 
Это принцип уважения автора текста к читателю и 
его времени. Иногда встречаются ответы, в 
которых и после третьего прочтения так и неясно, 
какое же решение и почему автор ответа считает 
верным. 



